# Angular 16 handling html event listeners and html transformation from drupal cms

Tags: angular, drupal

I'm currently in the process of evaluating the feasibility of using Angular with a Drupal site. The goal is to create a unified interface that connects with various services. However, I'm facing challenges when it comes to transforming the handling of event listeners tied to HTML classes and performing transformations on the HTML.

One important constraint is that rewriting all the content is not a viable option, and our content editors do not and will not have Angular knowledge. They should be able to work with no more complexity than class assignments.

For instance, our content editor might add a "lightbox" class to an image, and I need to show it in a modal when clicked. Similarly, for a table with a "search" class, I would prepend an input element and use it to filter the table using JavaScript.

I've explored various resources and courses on Angular, but most of them seem to focus on simple JSON responses that are added with [innerHTML] or ElementRef. In my case, I receive entire JSON fields that can contain multiple images, tables, and other dynamic HTML content with classes for actions all over the place, the field also varies in content from one page to another making it difficult to break it up into any specific form beyond some generalization.

What strategies or approaches exist in Angular to handle this situation effectively? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I figure i put some code example here to maybe clarify what i am trying to accomplish.

This would be what i would do in plain old html and javascript:

```html
<body>
    <article>
    <p>Some conent</p>    
    <a class="lightbox" href="large-image.jpg">
        <img src="small-image.jpg">
    </a>
    <p>Some content</p>
    </article>

    <script>
        const lightBox = document.querySelector('lightbox');

        lightBox.addEventListener('click', (link) => {
            link.lightbox(); // triggers a modal with large image 
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This is a simplified version of trying to do the same as above in angular. Unfinished since i don't know the answer.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div [innerHtml]="loadedHtml"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    loadedHtml: string;

    constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageService.getPage(1).subscribe((response) => {
            this.loadedHtml = response.data;
        });

       // bind a click event listener to the now loaded link 
       // with class lightbox inside the div to trigger a modal
       // with the bigger image
    }

}
```

Comment: with angular you will have a classic sort of model, view, controller approach.   The complexity of your model will not be limited.

Comment: the complexity i referred to was the html content, i can control the model and form of a page but not the content of a field that will be pure html and i can't figure out how to bind events to the html classes from json html string after loading them from the rest service. In vanilla javascript all i need to do is document.queryselector() and then i can add listeners and transform the data and then return it, i am trying to transfer the same concept into the angular world.

Comment: it's a different approach in Angular.  You won't be setting event handlers from JS... (events are evaluated by Angular according to what's set in view/controller)  JSON returned from server will not contain any HTML... only the model/data needs to be returned.  Client-side takes care of all markup.